# Decrease the number of redirects without www for www http for https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to make my url without www redirect to www and my url without https redirect to https in the minimum of possible redirects.

I'm using this rule

```
# BEGIN SSL Redirect
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
# END SSL Redirect
```

the problem is that this rule generates many redirects if I try to access this url

example.com

do it

http://example.com/ ==> http://www.example.com/ ==> https://www.example.com/

I would like you to do this

http://example.com/ ==> https://www.example.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
# BEGIN SSL + non www to www  Redirect
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
# END SSL + www Redirect
```

This will redirect both non-ssl and non-www to `https://www` in a single request.

If you are not on a proxy proxy server (ie : cloudflare..) then you will need to replace this line `RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http [OR]` with `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]` in order for this to work.

Comment: This line does not
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

 work it redirects to this:

https: // _% 7Bhttp_host% 7D /

so I changed because of that
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
but an error occurs
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: Sorry there was a slight typo. Please see the edit and try again.

Comment: @BrunoAndrade I updated the code.  Clear your browser cache and test it again